# Button click only fires when IP in the URL not computer name

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an asp.net webform. When I browse to the URL using the computer name ie: http://somecomputer/mypage.aspx the button click events do NOT fire. Other events do like selected index changed or text changed but the button click does not.

If I navigate to the page by IP, ie: http://192.168.100.1/mypage.aspx, then the button click fires and everything works as expected. Why is this and how can I fix it?

here is the button click html:

```
<div class="li_div">
<asp:Button ID="btnInventoryRpt" runat="server" 
Text="Load Report" OnClick="btnInventoryRpt_Click" CausesValidation="false" UseSubmitBehavior="False"  />
 </div>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
protected void btnInventoryRpt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        load_inventory_report();
    }
```

Comment: Some code please?

Comment: The page works fine if the IP is in the URL. What code would you like to see? I am trying to figure out why I can't browse to the page by computer name and have the button click fire.

Comment: The code for the button and the click event.  Are you publishing the code to a public site under IIS?

Comment: On an intranet. Even when I browse to the page on my own machine //localhost/mypage.aspx the button click won't fire. I will add the click event code.

Comment: I would first try to figure out why it doesn't work when you run it locally.  Is it hitting validation that it shouldn't?  Is there a JavaScript error?  Why are you using UseSubmitBehavior="false"?

Comment: I don't have any validation. It is just weird thing. I don't know why the other controls work as expected and not the button clicks. It is so weird. If I browse there with the IP it works perfectly. Just a head scratcher.

Comment: Seano666 - that is what I am trying to figure out. Why it won't work locally. I have tried everything I can think of.

Comment: Sounds like you need a test page, copy the code of this page onto a test page, and start paring it down further and further until it works.  Or you can go the other way and start with nothing on your test page, keep adding things to match your page in question until things stop working.